# PHP SOAP pass parameters a:DeserializationFailed error

Tags: api, soap, soap-client

I ma trying to pass values like below for $valueTicket

```
$default_value = array(
    'ticket' =>  $valueTicket,
    'customercode' => 'abcdefgh'
);
```

shows error **a:DeserializationFailed**

while same time if i pass static value then works fine like below example

```
$default_value = array(
        'ticket' =>  'zyx12-3iuyf-njfg-sdj-shjs',
        'customercode' => 'abcdefgh'
    );
```

can anyone know whats the problem please assist.

if anyone need any information regarding my issue then ask me.